# Phonegap unable to install platform

Tags: node.js, cordova

I'm following this documentation to get started with phonegap - http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

I have created the project Hello, then I've navigated into the project and from there if I type: cordova platform add android I have an error - 'cordova' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: This command worked for you? cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld

Comment: Yes it worked when i was in directory C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm but when i went to C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\hello to add a platform, cordova command doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the platform, go ahead and execute the build command as follows

```
cordova build ios
```

If you are using phonegap do the following

```
phonegap build ios
```